# If Else statement syntax error

Tags: php

I have the following function which in words should take user credentials and validate them. If they are valid insert them into the db. Once inserted check if they are successfully inserted. If not return false. If the email was invalid in the first place return false. Eclipse + Aptana plugin is reporting a syntax error with the last else section. It seems like it should be functioning correctly when I try to rationalize the code. I can confirm all of the {brackets} are in the correct hierarchical order

Here is the code:

```
   public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    if((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) && preg_match('/@.+\./', $email)); { //validate the email 
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())"); 

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details 
        $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false; //unsuccessful store
    }
     else { //THIS IS LINE 45
        //not a valid email
        return false;
    }
    }
}
```

It returns the following error:

```
05-23 11:07:10.758: E/JSON(1601): <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in <b>/home/content/40/8529140/html/webapps/projects/functions/DB_Functions.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br />
05-23 11:07:10.758: E/JSON Parser(1601): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: You should really indent your code properly - it helps finding missing or obsolete brackets.

Comment: semicolon in first if statement, and take out your last else part from inner if-else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `else` statement is in the wrong position with respect to the closing braces. If you move one of the `}`s before the second `else` it will work. Actually maybe it won't, you also have a stray `;`, but the other advice still stands.

If you indent your code more consistently, you won't be caught out by this sort of problem.

```
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    if ( //validate the email 
         filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) &&
         preg_match('/@.+\./', $email)
         ) {
        $result = mysql_query (
            "INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())"
        );
        if ($result) { // check for successful store
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false; //unsuccessful store
        }
    } else {
        //not a valid email
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. Learn to use PDO and parameterised queries.

Comment: **Don't** is a strong word :-P

Comment: Good advice as far as the indenting form, more constancy probably would have helped me catch it.

Answer (score 3):

```
if((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
      && preg_match('/@.+\./', $email)); { //<<<REMOVE THE ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing your braces properly and you had an extra semicolon after the outer `if`:

```
if((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) && preg_match('/@.+\./', $email)) { //validate the email 
   $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())"); 

   // check for successful store
   if ($result) {
      // get user details 
      $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
      // return user details
      return mysql_fetch_array($result);
   } else {
     return false; //unsuccessful store
   }
} // close of outer if
else {
    //not a valid email
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wrong error.... there is a semicolon after that 1st if statement...

Comment: @Neal: Fixed it, but also his outer if was not closed properly.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see the little semicolon on end of this? `if((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) && preg_match('/@.+\./', $email));`

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced a bracket. Try this

```
 public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    if((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) && preg_match('/@.+\./', $email)) { //validate the email 
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())"); 

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details 
        $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false; //unsuccessful store
    }
    }
     else {
        //not a valid email
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Wrong error.... there is a semicolon after that 1st if statement..

Comment: You should probably tell the OP what you fixed..

Answer (score -2):

Why do you have two `else {}` blocks at the end...? You can have only one.